How to prevent specific USB device (vendorId:ProductId) from having driver loaded
I am trying to setup Debian Linux host with KVM (libvirt) virtual machines. Host has some USB devices attached to it and I would like to pass-through one of them to the guest virtual machine. To do so the device must be unbound on the host.
I tried to set authorization param to 0 via custom udev rule:
ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7000", ATTR{authorized}="0"

and that indeed allows me to pass the device through and makes it visible inside guest, but any attempt to load cdc_acm driver there fails with can't load config #1, error -32.
When I blacklist cdc_acm driver in /etc/modprobe.d/ .conf file with following directives:
blacklist cdc_acm
install cdc_acm /bin/false

everything works as expected. Problem is that I have another device attached to host that requires cdc_acm driver but has different vendorId:productId.
My question is if there's any way to avoid binding specific device identified by vendorId:productId to cdc_acm driver but allow other devices.

Good question. If all else fails, a managed USB hub might help, e.g., https://www.usbgear.com/managed-hubs.html or https://www.amazon.com/Coolgear-Port-Managed-Surge-Protection/dp/B08S9VFJPJ/ref=sr_1_9. Perhaps switching the device in or out remotely might prevent driver being loaded... or not. However, these devices prices start at more than US$100.
